# Invalid Field Name error when creating Sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, application-pages

I'm trying to create a new Sharepoint page but I am getting the following error:

> Invalid field name. {50631c24-1371-4ecf-a5ae-ed41b03f4499}  .../Pages
>   TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation
>   ID: 8b1ea59e-2480-2029-28b8-63236dc7140d

Any ideas?

Comment: What name you are using to create page?

Answer (score 0):

The field “{50631c24-1371-4ecf-a5ae-ed41b03f4499}” in your error message is the “Hide physical URLs from search” column.

Go to Pages library settings->Content Types->click the relevant content type when you create the page. Re-add this “Hide physical URLs from search” column to the content type and check again.